# Redirect Non-WWW to www 

Tags: apache2

i have about 10 domains on my server

```
site1.com
site2.com
site3.com
```

i want redirect `non-www` to `www`

from `site1.com` to `www.site1.com`

from `site2.com` to `www.site2.com`

Should i add htaccess for each site?

can i short this job in apache config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following entry in your Apache configuration for each domain would do the trick. Note that you should be doing a `301` (permanent) redirect to make sure the search engines understand that your `www` address is the canonical one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com

Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: i don't want to redirect all domains to an domain!! i want just replace non-www by www, but in all sites on the server, site1.com to www.site1.com and site2.com to www.site2.com

Comment: Yes, you would copy the above entry to httpd.conf **for each** domain you want to redirect. Replace `example.com` with `site1.com`, for example.

Comment: that's mean i will repeat the code 10 times, but i am here to find something shorten